# Entity Framework - Manually Add Properties to Many-to-Many Relationship - Model First

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, ef-model-first

### Scenario:

As mentioned [here](http://www.itq.nl/blogs/post/Code-First-Entity-Framework-Additional-properties-on-many-to-many-join-tables.aspx), once you add additional properties to a simple join table (many-to-many relationship), it's no longer a hidden association.  These questions also address this:

- [Many-to-Many relationship in Entity Framework with relationship informantion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13041163/many-to-many-relationship-in-entity-framework-with-relationship-informantion)
- [How can I add properties to an association (relationship) using the Entity Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4233585/how-can-i-add-properties-to-an-association-relationship-using-the-entity-frame)

The existing code already uses the simple, automatically hidden navigation properties, and there are some minor customizations to the autogenerated tables, and so I'd like to avoid refactoring the entire project when I alter the underlying relationship table.

### Question:

Is there a way so that both the automatic navigation (many-to-many) accessors can remain, but I can also access the relationship entity directly?

I could just write my own accessors selecting from the relationship table, but then they're no longer `EntityCollections` and thus I'm concerned that I lose whatever magic happens under the hood like tracking, etc.

Can I manually add `EntityCollections` to entities?

### Expectation:

Originally: `Product* <-> *Offer`

- a Product has many Offers (like 50% off, BOGO)
- the same Offer could apply to many Products ("Red Shirt" and "Blue Pants" are BOGO)

Desired:  `Product* <-[sort]-> *Offer`

- When I list Offers for a Product, I can sort them independently
- i.e. "Red Shirt" has "50% off" then "BOGO", but "Blue Pants" shows "BOGO" then "50% off"

then I would want to be able to do:

```
// original access, do stuff
List<Offer> applicableOffers = currentProduct.Offers.Where(...);
// hit up the join table directly for properties
var applicableOffersInOrder = applicableOffers.OrderBy(o => o.ProductOffers.Sort);
```

rather than

```
var applicableOffersInOrder = currentProduct.ProductOffers
        .OrderBy(o => o.Sort)
        .Offers.Where(...);
```

Comment: hm...Since I only really care about the sorting in one direction, I wonder if I could create multiple one-to-many associations in the Model Designer like @ladislav does here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9043453/entity-framework-model-first-how-to-create-association-with-properties

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the *easiest* way to do it is simply add two properties manually in a non-autogenerated `partial` class:

```
partial class Offer
{
    public IQueryable<Product> Products 
    { 
       get { return this.ProductOffers.Select(x => x.Product); } 
    }
}
partial class Product
{
    public IQueryable<Offer> Offers 
    { 
       get { return this.ProductOffers.OrderBy(x => x.Sort).Select(x => x.Offer); } 
    }
}
```

This won't help for when you want to add a new `ProductOffer`, but since you actually have extra data (`Sort`) you should be doing that via the `ProductOffers` collection anyway.

Comment: That's what I figured.  However, From what I understand it should be `IQueryable` to get the benefits of lazy-loading, etc; I was hoping I could take it a step further and declare it as an `EntityCollection` the same way the `.edmx` does.

Comment: You're right, `IQueryable` is a better choice.  Edited.  What do you gain from making it an `EntityCollection`?

Comment: honestly I don't know, but I assume there's a good reason it's originally an `EntityCollection` when EF does it.  EF does it's own change tracking and optimized fetching, so I don't want to miss out on any of the magic just because I want less typing.

Comment: Note that EF will not accept these properties in a query because they aren't navigation properties. I would be hesitant to use such shortcuts. Too easy to run into lazy loading exceptions because it is not conspicuous that you should `Include` `ProductOffers` and `Offer` in the query to have the `Offers` available after converting to `IEnumerable`.

Comment: accepting in lieu of a more desirable solution...I tried manually adding the original autogenerated `.edmx` `AssociationSet` stuff, but couldn't get around the duplicate naming.

Comment: @drzaus - I wish I had a better solution for you.  Good luck!